# Nesting ListView into DropdownMenu

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, drop-down-menu

I have created a custom ListView and I want to nest it into my Dropdownmenu as the item. Currently, I am getting  the 'NoSuchMethodError : The method 'map' was called on null'. I can't seem to map it right. I am very new to Flutter.

- The code for the ListView

```
class TheDetails extends StatelessWidget {

  TheDetails({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      itemExtent: 70.0,
      children: <CustomListItem>[
        CustomListItem(
          accName: 'Salary Account',
          accNumber: 'Savings XXX-X-XX563-9',
          accBalance: '56,302.56',
        ),
        CustomListItem(
          accName: 'Salary Account 2',
          accNumber: 'Savings XXX-X-XX563-9',
          accBalance: '89,302.56',
        ),
        CustomListItem(
          accName: 'Vayu Meetang',
          accNumber: 'Savings XXX-X-XX563-9',
          accBalance: '100,505.56',
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

- The code for the DropdownButton

```
class SelectAccount extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SelectAccountState createState() => _SelectAccountState();
}

class _SelectAccountState extends State<SelectAccount> {
  var dropdownValue;
  var accountNames;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(width: 375.0, height: 120.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      ),
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
        value: dropdownValue,
        underline: Container(
          height: 2,
        ),
        icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
        color: Colors.blue[500],),
        onChanged: (String newValue) {
          setState(() {
            dropdownValue = newValue;
          });
        },
        items: accountNames.map((item){
          return DropdownMenuItem(
            value: item,
            child: TheDetails(),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `.map()` on `accountNames` which is not initialized, and therefore `null` at least on the first build. So doing `var accountNames = [];` will solve the issue.

A cleaner way to add a widget for each member of a list is :

```
items: [
    for(var name in accountNames)
        DropdownMenuItem(value: name, child: TheDetails()),
]
```

**EDIT:** Putting everything together :

```
// in top-level or another file
class Account {
  Account(this.name, this.number, this.balance);
  String name;
  String number;
  String balance;
}


// in _SelectAccountState or a provider
var selectedAccount = 'Savings XXX-X-XX563-9';

var accounts = [
  Account(
    'Salary Account',
    'Savings XXX-X-XX563-7',
    '56,302.56',
  ),
  Account(
    'Salary Account 2',
    'Savings XXX-X-XX563-8',
    '89,302.56',
        ),
  Account(
    'Vayu Meetang',
    'Savings XXX-X-XX563-9',
    '100,505.56',
  ),
];

// In the build method
DropdownButton<String>(
  value: selectedAccount,
  items: [
  for(var account in accounts)
    DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: account.number,
      child: Text(account.name),),
  ],
  onChanged: (val) => setState(() => selectedAccount = val)
),
```

Comment: hai thank you so much for the suggestion. I've tried it, I got an error on the 'for' statement. Can you help me with that ? Thanks

Comment: In your pubspec.yaml, the minimum SDK version should be at least 2.6.0.

Comment: the error is resolved, but when I click on the dropdown, it doesnt expand to show the list.

Comment: That's because the list is empty, you need to populate it. Do you want all the CustomListItems for one choice, or one choice per CustomListItem ?

Comment: I want it to be one choice  per CustomListItem.

Comment: I edited the answer to provide an extensive example. You might want to use a state management solution like provider to manage the state, away from the UI code. See [Simple app state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

Comment: thank you so much ! but I think I understood wrong, does 'one choice per CustomListItem ' mean just the name/number/balance ? because I want all three 'name,number and balance' to be one item.

Comment: DropdownMenuItem's child is limited in height. It's meant to be one line of text.

Comment: i see, does this mean I should opt for custom widget ? thank you so much for your help ! appreciate it.

Comment: Hai, if I put the details of each account into a card, and nest the card as the items of the dropdown, would that be possible ? If yes, how do I map the cards as the item ? Thanks !

Comment: The dropdown items must be DropdownMenuItem, so unfortunately, no.